# Не запускается программа на Qt5. До этого запускалась стабильно, после обновления проблемы начались

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я просто перенес файлы скрипта в новую папку, создал новое окружение и загрузил все зависимости с помощью pip3

При запуске программы пишет вот такую ошибку.

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. -  Переустановка приложения может решить проблему.
Попробуйте в новом окружении установить Qt вручную. Может проблема в версиях пакетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается командой

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```